# Why cant ajax find php file when submitting form?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form, making an ajax post request but it wont find the php file.Ive tried anything and read through so many posts here and tried everything suggested but nothing helps.

1. I tried to use an absolute path as that was suggested somewhere. Doesnt work.
2. relative path doesnt work either
3. I tried to put the submit button outside of my form in my html file (was suggested in another post) - doesnt work either.
   Anyone knows why?
   EDIT: Im getting a 404

file structure:

```
myApp/app/js/contact.js
myApp/app/mail/contact.php
myApp/app/index.html
```

html:

```
    <section id="contact">
        <form>
            name:
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name"> email:
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email"> message:
            <input id="message" type="text" name="message">
            <button id="submit">send</button>
        </form>
    </section>
```

app/js/contact.js:

```
  $('#submit').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault() ;
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();

        console.log("name", name, email);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/app/mail/contact.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                message: message
            }
        })
    });
```

mail/contact.php:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'Contact Form';
    $to = 'myemail@yahoo.com';
    $subject = 'Message from my page ';
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: What is the URL of the HTML document? What URL is requested (use the Network tab in your developer tools) when the Ajax request is made?

Comment: And what was the error you got? What makes you think it *"wont find the php file"*?

Comment: Did you look into the server logs?

Comment: The url:   http://localhost:3000/ (thats it). Sorry I forgo to say- Im getting a 404. Also I dont have any server logs- Im not using any server side code/php for more than this form.

Answer (score 0):

In your html file, put your scripts before `</body>` tag

```
<section id="contact">
    <form>
        name:
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name"> email:
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email"> message:
        <input id="message" type="text" name="message">
        <button id="submit">send</button>
    </form>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/js/contact.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I do that. The problem is not that my js file isnt found, but my php file

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to solve your issue, but this is a better ux

give your `<form>` a class or ID and execute your form submission on a form submit

so it would be

```
$('.formClassName').submit(function(event){

});
```

This will allow the form submission to fire off the AJAX event on the submit button click, as well as if the user hits the enter button.

Comment: Im already doing that just that, I gave my form the id 'submit' but that didnt help either

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`url: "/app/mail/contact.php",`

use:

`url: "mail/contact.php",`

Comment: is your file structure correct? could you double check it because i tested the code based on your given file structure and it doesn't have any problem. Also,is there any error in your web browser's console or in network?

Comment: yes my file structure is as I posted it. Im getting a 404 error. Maybe I should mention that I am also using gulp.I didnt think this could have anything to do with loading files in this case, but maybe it does